# Reg expression for checking first letter of a string is an alphabet in Android

Tags: android, regex

Can you please help me to get a regular expression for finding whether first letter of the string is an alphabet.

Here my requirement is to block user to type other characters apart from alphabets as first letter in edit text.For example like this,

```
edtTxtFirstname.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
            new InputFilter.LengthFilter(30),
            new CharacterInputFilter(Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]")) });
```

Thanks

JRH

Comment: Do you __really__ need a regex for it?

Comment: @devnull, what is other option for this, instead of TextWatcher? I should not allow user to type other character as First. After that, we allow it.

Comment: Hi I update the answer check it. It works like charm as your requirement. First character will automatically converted to upercase and only alphabet will allow to input.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
 String strRegExpr= "[a-zA-Z]";

        if (youstr.matches(strRegExpr))
        {
            // your entered value is Alphabetic
            Log.i("Character is Alphabate", "Check this"+yourstr);
        }
        else
        {
            // your entered value is Numeric
            Log.i("Character is Numaric", "Check this"+yourstr);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own filter like this

```
InputFilter myFilter = new InputFilter() {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        if (dstart == 0) {
            try {
                Character c = source.charAt(0);
                if (Character.isLetter(c) && Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    if (Character.isLetter(c) && Character.isLowerCase(c))
                        return "" + Character.toUpperCase(c);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(30), myFilter });
```